# Is possible to define ansible_tmp variable in playbook?

Tags: ansible

I want to copy large files using ansible. Destination servers have a dedicated partition with adequate storage space. I noticed that ansible uses its temporary directory which defined by remote_tmp variable.

I would to copy directly files in the dedicated partition without passing by temporary directory.

Is it possible to define remote_tmp variable in playbook for this case ? I'm running ansible 1.8.

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: @Anurag why does he have to tell you. either you can answer or you can't.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `ansible_remote_tmp` variable after ansible version 2.5.

```
ansible-playbook test.yaml --extra-vars "ansible_remote_tmp=/tmp/.ansible/tmp"
```

Answer (score 6):

You can change [remote_tmp](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_configuration.html#remote-tmp) in the Ansible configuration.
Ansible uses a configuration tree that looks first in the working dir, so you can place an `ansible.cfg` file alongside the playbook that changes only this value and it won't affect playbooks in other directories.

But I'd recommend to use [synchronize_module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/synchronize_module.html) if you need advanced options for copying files.

Answer (score 2):

In your inventory file, you can declare it:

```
node-0 ansible_host=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx ansible_user=root
node-1 ansible_host=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx  ansible_user=root
node-2 ansible_host=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx  ansible_user=root

[xx]
node-0
node-1
node-2

[xxx]
node-0

[xxxx]
node-1
node-2

[all:vars] 
ansible_remote_tmp=/tmp/.ansible
```