# Can I modify Ansible 'remote_tmp' on a per task basis?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I am running some tasks with `delegate_to`.  When those tasks run, they use the same `remote_tmp` directory setup from the *ansible.cfg*.
However, due to permissions and directory size issues, I need to change the `remote_tmp` directory for tasks that I am using `delegate_to` for.

Example:

```yaml
- name: Create Temp Dir
  delegate_to: localhost
  file:
    path: "{{ my_temp_dir }}"
    state: directory
```

I am using Ansible 2.3.2.

Comment: _I am using Ansible 2.3.2._ > you should seriously consider upgrading: https://access.redhat.com/support/policy/updates/ansible-engine

Answer (score 3):

As of 2.5, yes, changing `remote_tmp`, which is an `ansible_*` variable is something possible, by adding it to the `vars` of the said task.

For example:

```yaml
- tempfile:
    state: file
    suffix: temp
  vars:
    ansible_remote_tmp: /tmp/temp_file_1_task
```

---

Given a playbook with the two tasks:

```yaml
- tempfile:
    state: file
    suffix: temp
  vars:
    ansible_remote_tmp: /tmp/temp_file_1_task

- tempfile:
    state: file
    suffix: temp
  vars:
    ansible_remote_tmp: /tmp/temp_file_2_task
```

A reduced version of the extra verbose log would yield:

> <127.0.0.1> EXEC /bin/sh -c '/usr/local/bin/python **/tmp/temp_file_1_task**/ansible-tmp-1642453716.1902952-890-119314712082250/AnsiballZ_tempfile.py && sleep 0'

and

> <127.0.0.1> EXEC /bin/sh -c '/usr/local/bin/python **/tmp/temp_file_2_task**/ansible-tmp-1642453716.6039782-905-172576654053914/AnsiballZ_tempfile.py && sleep 0'

Comment: I tried what you provided above using 'tempfile' module with and without 'delegate_to' to modify the "remote tmp" directory for Ansible on the host I am 'delegating to'.  It is still using the setting in the 'ansible.cfg' (remote_tmp).    I would think that there is an environment variable or task variable that could be modified for setting the 'remote_tmp' directory.

Comment: Mhm yes, it looks like it became an `ansible_*` variable as of 2.5, from what I see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65418336/2123530). (I had to boot a python 2.x container to test and saw the same, indeed)

Comment: thanks for the help!

Comment: Thanks for sharing `ansible_remote_tmp`; super useful to avoid this warning on the first playbook running as root (before setting up the ansible user). Great!